# How do I get the T part of an array T[]?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

When exploring, through Reflection, a generic type such as `IEnumerable<T>`, I can find `T` by doing:

```
public Type Demo<TSequence>()
{
    return typeof(TSequence).GenericTypeArguments[0];
}
```

For instance:

```
typeof(Collection<short>).GenericTypeArguments[0].FullName == "System.Int16"
```

The specifics of arrays means that this approach doesn't work for arrays, since they don't have generic parameters per se. The only way I've found to actually get the type of the element of an array is to do:

```
public Type Demo<TArray>()
{
    return typeof(TArray)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .DeclaredMethods
        .Single(m => m.Name == "Get")
        .ReturnType;
}
```

which is a contrived, ugly and error prone hack.

How do I find the type of elements of an array?

Comment: `typeof(TArray).GetElementType()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays predate generics in .NET, so this isn't really surprising.

It also means that there's a special reflection method to get exactly what you want:

```
typeof(int[]).GetElementType()
```

gives you `System.Int32`.

There's other similar methods to get information about arrays - like `GetArrayRank` and `IsArray`, and a separate reflection method to *create* an arbitrary array, `MakeArrayType`.